# convert string allow null col to int?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-expressions

I want to convert string to int my string type  [DT_WSTR] and my expression

```
ISNULL(col) || TRIM(col) == "" ? (DT_I4)0 : (DT_I4)col
```

I get this error 
[Derived Column [518]] Error: The conditional operation failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got something that doesn't convert to an integer value in your source data.

Since the expression language doesn't have a tryparse method, the cleanest mechanism is to use a script component as a Transformation and leverage the .NET methods.

1. Connect a Script Component to your source.
2. On the Input Columns tab, check `col` as ReadOnly.
3. On the Inputs and Outputs tab, expand Output 0, click Output Columns and select `Add Column`
4. Rename this column to CleanCol and leave with the default data type of DT_I4
5. Click back to the Script tab and click `Edit Script...`
6. Use the following method in your code

Line here so formatting picks up

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    int colOut = 0;
    if (!Int32.TryParse(Row.col, out colOut))
    {
        Row.CleanCol_IsNull = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Row.CleanCol = colOut;
    }
}
```

Here's my source query

```
SELECT
    D.*
FROM
(
VALUES
    (N'1')
,   ('')
,   ('0')
,   ('3')
,   ('X') -- Uncomment this one to generate error
,   (NULL)
) D(col);
```

### Results

As I think about it a bit longer, in the above script, if you wanted to have zero outputted for "bad" values, replace the first action in the if statement with `Row.CleanCol = 0;` Otherwise, this will make numbers of numbers and NULL of non-numbers.

[image]